# Angular - get response from more than one request

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I need to trigger 2 requests.
Based on the first one I need to trigger the second one, and at the end return response from both requests:

```
  getDetails(userName: string) {
    this.rep$ = this.http.get<IRep[]>(`${this.api}/users/${userName}/coll1`);
    return this.rep$.pipe(switchMap(repos => {
      return repos.filter((repo) => {
        return repo.active === false;
      }).map((repo) => {
        return this.http.get<IColl2[]>(`${this.api}/repos/${userName}/${repo.name}/coll2`);
      });
    }, (resp1, resp2) => [resp1, resp2])
    );

  }
```

Comment: Do you need information from the first request to start the 2nd request?

Comment: yes exactly, I need one property from the 1 response to create api url for the second call. and then return array from the first and the second call

Comment: Do you want to do the second request for each of the repos returned by the first request that are not active?

Comment: Yes, for each item returned by the first request I need to get one property and trigger second request. Then return both responses it should be 2 arrays of objects or even better some concatenation like [{req1.props, req2.props}....]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what you need you can use `combineLatest` to wait for all the second requests and the add the first request result to them:

```
getDetails(userName: string) {
    this.rep$ = this.http.get<IRep[]>(`${this.api}/users/${userName}/coll1`);
    return this.rep$.pipe(switchMap(repos => {
      const inactiveRepos = repos.filter((repo) => !repo.active);
      combineLatest(
        inactiveRepos.map((repo) => this.http.get<IColl2[]>(`${this.api}/repos/${userName}/${repo.name}/coll2`))
      ).pipe(
        map((responses) => responses.map((response) => ({response1: repos, response2: response})))
      )
    }
}
```

In the above exemple the result will be an array that for each element will have the first response in the property response1 and the second response in the response2 property.

**UPDATE**

I forgot to add the return statement to the combineLatest:

```
getDetails(userName: string) {
    this.rep$ = this.http.get<IRep[]>(`${this.api}/users/${userName}/coll1`);
    return this.rep$.pipe(switchMap(repos => {
      const inactiveRepos = repos.filter((repo) => !repo.active);
      return combineLatest(
        inactiveRepos.map((repo) => this.http.get<IColl2[]>(`${this.api}/repos/${userName}/${repo.name}/coll2`))
      ).pipe(
        map((responses) => responses.map((response) => ({response1: repos, response2: response})))
      )
    }
}
```

Comment: it doeasn't work, I am getting Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction<unknown, [unknown, void]> on the second pipe

Comment: From where do you import the `combineLatest` operator?

Doest this exemple work for you?

    const test = of([1, 2,3, 4]);

    test.pipe(
      switchMap((resp) => {
        const requests =[of(2), of(3), of(4)];
        return combineLatest(
          requests
        ).pipe(
          map(requests => requests.map(req => ({r1: resp, r2: req})))
        )
      })
    );

Comment: yeh, just noticed that imported from operators instead of just from rxjs. but still sth is wrong, You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

Comment: got it, missing return in second request

Comment: can U explain, why combineLatest is needed?

Comment: The `combineLatest` operator will wait until all the observables inside it emit at least one value. So in this example, after you are making the first request, we make multiple second requests and wait until all of them are finished. After they are finished in the last map we aggregate the first response to them. 
The bottom line is we need it to wait for all the requests to be done and then aggregate the first response to the responses provided by them